# Environment Subtable not defined

Tags: tables, subcaption, subtables

I'm trying to insert a subtable into my document. I have loaded the subcaption package, as well as installed the caption package via MikTex. However I still get the `Environment subtable undefined. \begin{subtable}` error, as well as the ".5" from `.5\linewidth` put in front of my table. How can I fix this?

Here's an extract from the document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=3.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{table}
        \centering
        \caption{\textbf{Zusammensetzung des Mastermixes für die 
                 PCR Reagenzien.}}
        \begin{subtable}{.5\linewidth}
        \begin{tabular}{r l}
            $4.0\mu l$ & dNTPs ($10mM$) \\
            $12.0\mu l$ & Oligo forw-\textit{TRP1} ($5\mu M$) \\
            $12.0\mu l$ & Oligo rev-\textit{TRP1} ($5\mu M$) \\
            $20.0\mu l$ & 10 x Taq Puffer \\
            $12.0\mu l$ & \ce{MgCl2} \\
            $132.0\mu l$ & \ce{H2O} \\
            $4.0\mu l$ & Taq Polymerase ($1u*\mu l^{-1}$)\\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}
    \hspace{\fill}
    \begin{subtable}{.5\linewidth}
        \begin{tabular}{r l}
            $4.0\mu l$ & dNTPs ($10mM$) \\
            $12.0\mu l$ & Oligo forw-\textit{LEU2} ($5\mu M$) \\
            $12.0\mu l$ & Oligo rev-\textit{LEU2} ($5\mu M$) \\
            $20.0\mu l$ & 10 x Taq Puffer \\
            $12.0\mu l$ & \ce{MgCl2} \\
            $132.0\mu l$ & \ce{H2O} \\
            $4.0\mu l$ & Taq Polymerase ($1u*\mu l^{-1}$)\\
            
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}
    \end{table}
```

And here's the errors this is generating:

```
44: Environment subtable undefined. \begin{subtable}
44: Missing number, treated as zero. \begin{subtable}{.5\linewidth}
44: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \begin{subtable}{.5\linewidth}
54: \begin{table} on input line 41 ended by \end{subtable}. \end{subtable}
56: Environment subtable undefined. \begin{subtable}
56: Missing number, treated as zero. \begin{subtable}{.5\linewidth}
56: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \begin{subtable}{.5\linewidth}
67: \begin{table} on input line 41 ended by \end{subtable}. \end{subtable}
: No \author given.
38: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
38: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
```

Please note that the code shown above is just an extract and the line numbers in the error messages won't match. If there's some confusion and you need the line numbers applicable to the uploaded code please let me know.

I'm absolutely stumped about this, I don't know what to do.

Thank you all very much for your help in advance.

Max

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If I create something compilable from the code you provide (which means essentially adding `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`), the first error (and this is always the one you should look at first) tells me: "Package subcaption Error: This package can't be used in cooperation with the subfig package.". So, I would suggest that you delete the two (!) instances of `\usepackage{subfig}` in your preamble.

Comment: Well ... that worked. Thank you very much! I did not get this error, so I never tried looking for any non-compatible packages. Anyway, thank you very much again, this solved my issue.

Comment: Hm, this is what [minimal working examples (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) are for: Try to reduce your document as much as possible until the error goes aways. This process often helps you to narrow down the problem and, most often than not, even solve it on your own. I am glad, this worked out for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User @JasperHabicht has already solved the OP's immediate issue. The solution? Don't load both `subfig` and `subcaption`.

There's still a major issue with the OP's code: The `subtable` machinery isn't used at all! A `subtable` environment is basically a `minipage` that knows what to do if it encounters a `\caption` directive. Since no such instances occur, there's really no point in using `subtable` environments to begin with. Instead, I suggest the two `tabular` environments simply be separated by `\hspace{\fill}`.

I would also like to recommend loading the `siunitx` package and using its `\qty` and `\unit` macros to typeset quantities and their associated scientific units in a widely recognized, and less hackish, format.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
%% (I've simplified the preamble to a bare minimum)
\usepackage[left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm,%
            top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{textfont=bf}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}% for \qty macro

\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\caption{Zusammensetzung des Mastermixes für die PCR Reagenzien\textmd{.}}

\begin{tabular}[t]{@{} rl @{}}
\qty{4.0}{\micro\litre}  & dNTPs (\qty{10}{\milli M}) \\
\qty{12.0}{\micro\litre} & Oligo forw-\textit{TRP1} (\qty{5}{\micro M}) \\
\qty{12.0}{\micro\litre} & Oligo rev-\textit{TRP1} (\qty{5}{\micro M}) \\
\qty{20.0}{\micro\litre} & 10 $\times$ Taq Puffer \\
\qty{12.0}{\micro\litre} & \ce{MgCl2} \\
\qty{132.0}{\micro\litre}& \ce{H2O} \\
\qty{4.0}{\micro\litre}  & Taq Polymerase (\qty{1}{u(\micro\liter)\tothe{-1}})
\end{tabular}%
\hspace{\fill}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{} rl @{}}
\qty{4.0}{\micro\litre}  & dNTPs (\qty{10}{\milli M}) \\
\qty{12.0}{\micro\litre} & Oligo forw-\textit{LEU2} (\qty{5}{\micro M}) \\
\qty{12.0}{\micro\litre} & Oligo rev-\textit{LEU2} (\qty{5}{\micro M}) \\
\qty{20.0}{\micro\litre} & 10 $\times$ Taq Puffer \\
\qty{12.0}{\micro\litre} & \ce{MgCl2} \\
\qty{132.0}{\micro\litre}& \ce{H2O} \\
\qty{4.0}{\micro\litre}  & Taq Polymerase (\qty{1}{u(\micro\liter)\tothe{-1}})
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```